# Dynamic class loading in Python 2.6: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'plugins' not found while handling absolute import

Tags: python, plugins, import, dynamic-class-loaders

I am working on a plugin system where plugin modules are loaded like this:

```
def load_plugins():
   plugins=glob.glob("plugins/*.py")
   instances=[]
   for p in plugins:
      try:
         name=p.split("/")[-1]
         name=name.split(".py")[0]
         log.debug("Possible plugin: %s", name)
         f, file, desc=imp.find_module(name, ["plugins"])
         plugin=imp.load_module('plugins.'+name, f, file, desc)
         getattr(plugin, "__init__")(log)
         instances=instances+plugin.get_instances()
      except Exception as e:
         log.info("Failed to load plugin: "+str(p))
         log.info("Error: %s " % (e))
         log.info(traceback.format_exc(e))
   return instances
```

The code works, but for each import statement in the plugin code i get a warning like this:

```
plugins/plugin.py:2: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'plugins' not found while handling absolute import
  import os
```

No errors are reported for the main program code, and the plugins work.

Can somebody explain what the warning means and what I doing wrong. Do I need to create an empty plugins module separately and import it to keep python happy?

Comment: for the record: `'plugins'` in `Parent module 'plugins' not found` comes from the `name` value passed to [imp.load_module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_module), eg. `"plugins.something"` in `imp.load_module("plugins.something")`. In my case the `name` value was like `".something"` and thus message contained `''` instead of `'plugins'`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the directory `plugins` were a real package (contained `__init__.py` fine), you could easily use pkgutils to enumerate its plugin files and load them.

```
import pkgutil
# import our package
import plugins
list(pkgutil.iter_modules(plugins.__path__))
```

However, it can work without a plugin package anyway, try this:

```
import pkgutil
list(pkgutil.iter_modules(["plugins"]))
```

Also it is possible to make a package that only exists at runtime:

```
import types
import sys
plugins = types.ModuleType("plugins")
plugins.__path__ = ["plugins"]

sys.modules["plugins"] = plugins
import plugins.testplugin
```

However that hack that was mostly for fun!

Answer (score 16):

If the plugins directory does not have an `__init__.py`, it isn't a package, so when you create `plugins.whatever`, Python warns you that such a thing shouldn't really exist. (It couldn't be created by "`import plugins.whatever`" no matter what your path is.)

Also,

- Don't split on `/`, which is unportable. Use `os.path.split`.
- Don't use `.split(".py")` to get the name without the extension, which is buggy. Use `os.path.splitext`.
- Don't use `getattr` with a string literal. `getattr(plugin, "__init__")` is spelled `plugin.__init__`.
- I am confused why you are calling a module-level `__init__` function. This doesn't seem right. Perhaps you want a "set_logger" function or better, to instantiate a class that takes a logger.
- Don't use `L = L + some_other_list` to extend a list, use the `extend` method, which has better performance and is more idiomatic.
- Don't squash unknown exceptions by `except Exception`. If you cannot plan to do something sane in response to an exception, your program cannot go on sanely.

Comment: Note that the plugins directory is not intended to be a package, and not imported (i want to cherry pick files from it). The rest of the code is compiled as an egg and run directly using "python -m". I never add the plugin directory to the sys.path.

Comment: Right, but if you have a plugin `foo`, you have told it that it is `plugins.foo`, so it thinks it's part of the `plugins` package (which doesn't exist). When within `foo.py` you `import os` (or if you had `imported anythingelse`), you get that warning because `plugins` doesn't really exist.

Comment: (This means your options are to ignore the warning, change your naming scheme, or change your structure to match what Python expects.)

Comment: `except Exception` does not catch all exceptions, notably not SystemExit or KeyboardInterrupt. Sincie Py 2.6 not GeneratorExit either.

Comment: I think I understand that, thanks for the explanation. And thanks for the help with my general Python. It will take a while to master the API and know how things should be done. EDIT: Ninja post by Mike: Is there no way to create an empty package?

Comment: A package is a directory with an `__init__.py` file in it.

Comment: @kaizer.se, I had forgotten that a couple common exceptions do not subclass `Exception`. The base advice remains: you shouldn't silence exceptions you cannot understand and continue with your program; does this do something reasonable in response to `MemoryError`?

Comment: Then the solution becomes to add an empty package with the __init__.py to the egg. It seems to work well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't see anything idiomatically wrong with using `+` to combine two lists. Otherwise great answer.

Comment: @Mark, in the original code, we're using Shlemiel the painter's algorithm http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html

Comment: @MikeGraham +1 for the reminder to use list.extend (just yesterday I used "+" and forgot about extend). +2 for the link to a joelOn post from 2001. #tripdownmemorylane.

Comment: "Don't squash unknown exceptions by `except Exception`." --  I think this is sane in the context of loading plugins. You don't want your whole application shutting down just because a plugin messed up, especially in a GUI-only environment.

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is with the dot ('.') in the module name:

`imp.load_module('plugins.'+name, f, file, desc)`

Don't include a '.' after 'plugins', or Python will think it's a module path.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding below statement at the beginning of import statements.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) documentation has been updated since this was answered. It now addresses this issue specifically in the [`find_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.find_module) method.

> This function does not handle hierarchical module names (names containing dots). In order to find *P.M*, that is, submodule *M* of package *P*, use [`find_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.find_module) and [`load_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_module) to find and load package *P*, and then use [`find_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.find_module) with the *path* argument set to `P.__path__`. When *P* itself has a dotted name, apply this recipe recursively.

Note that `P.__path__` is already a list when supplying it to [`find_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.find_module). Also note what the [`find_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.find_module) documentation says about finding packages.

> If the module is a package, *file* is `None`, *pathname* is the package path and the last item in the *description* tuple is [`PKG_DIRECTORY`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.PKG_DIRECTORY).

So from the OP's question, to import the plugin without the `RuntimeError` warnings, follow the directions in the updated Python documentation:

```
# first find and load the package assuming it is in
# the current working directory, '.'

f, file, desc = imp.find_module('plugins', ['.'])
pkg = imp.load_module('plugins', f, file, desc)

# then find the named plugin module using pkg.__path__
# and load the module using the dotted name

f, file, desc = imp.find_module(name, pkg.__path__)
plugin = imp.load_module('plugins.' + name, f, file, desc)
```