# Alternatives to imp.find_module?

Tags: python, namespaces, importerror, pylint

### Background

I've grown tired of the issue with pylint not being able to import files when you use namespace packages and divide your code-base into separate folders. As such I started digging into the astNG source-code which has been identified as the source of the trouble (see bugreport [8796](http://www.logilab.org/ticket/8796) on astng). At the heart of the issue seems to be the use of pythons own `imp.find_module` in the process of finding imports.

What happens is that the import's first (sub)package - `a` in `import a.b.c` - is fed to `find_module` with a `None` path. Whatever path comes back is then fed into `find_module` the next pass in the look up loop where you try to find `b` in the previous example.

Pseudo-code from logilab.common.modutils:

```
path = None
while import_as_list:
      try:
           _, found_path, etc = find_module(import_as_list[0], path)
      #exception handling and checking for a better version in the .egg files
      path = [found_path]
      import_as_list.pop(0)
```

### The Problem

This is what's broken: you only get the first best hit from `find_module`, which may or may not have your subpackages in it. If you DON'T find the subpackages, you have no way to back out and try the next one.

I tried explicitly using sys.path instead of None, so that the result could be removed from the path list and a second attempt be made, but python's module finder is clever enough that there doesn't have to be an exact match in the paths, making this approach unusable - to the best of my knowledge anyway.

### Teary-eyed Plea

Is there an alternative to find_modules which will return *ALL* possible matches or take an exclude list? I'm also open to completely different solutions. Preferably not patching python by hand, but it wouldn't be impossible - at least for a local solution.

(Caveat emptor: I'm running python 2.6 and for reasons of current company policy can't upgrade, suggestions for p3k etc won't get marked as accepted unless it's the only answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've grown tired of this limitation in PyLint too.

I don't know a replacement for imp.find_modules(), but I think I found another way to deal with namespace packages in PyLint. See my comment on the bug report you linked to (http://www.logilab.org/ticket/8796).

The idea is to use pkg_resources to find namespace packages. Here's my addition to `logilab.common.modutils._module_file()`, just after `while modpath`:

```
  while modpath:
      if modpath[0] in pkg_resources._namespace_packages and len(modpath) > 1:
          module = sys.modules[modpath.pop(0)]
          path = module.__path__
```

This not very refined and only handles top-level namespace packages though.

Comment: Top level namespace packages are enough for my needs, I really hope this (or something more general) gets worked into the source post haste! I'm very glad you managed to find a fix where I drew a blank :)

Answer (score 4):

Since Python 2.5, the right way to do this is with [pkgutil.iter_modules()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules) (for a flat list) or [pkgutil.walk_packages()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.walk_packages) (for a subpackage tree).  Both are fully compatible with namespace packages.

For example, if I wanted to find just the subpackages/submodules of 'jmb', I would do:

```
import jmb, pkgutil
for (module_loader, name, ispkg) in pkgutil.iter_modules(jmb.__path__, 'jmb.'):
    # 'name' will be 'jmb.foo', 'jmb.bar', etc.
    # 'ispkg' will be true if 'jmb.foo' is a package, false if it's a module
```

You can also use iter_modules or walk_packages to walk *all* the modules on sys.path; see the docs linked above for details.

Answer (score 0):

warning + disclaimer: not tested yet!

before:

```
for part in parts:
    modpath.append(part)
    curname = '.'.join(modpath)
    # ...
    if module is None:
        mp_file, mp_filename, mp_desc = imp.find_module(part, path)
        module = imp.load_module(curname, mp_file, mp_filename, mp_desc)
```

after: <sup>- thanks [pjeby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14820895/611007) for mentioning [`pkgutil`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules)!</sup>

```
for part in parts:
    modpath.append(part)
    curname = '.'.join(modpath)
    # ...
    if module is None:
        # + https://stackoverflow.com/a/14820895/611007
        # # mp_file, mp_filename, mp_desc = imp.find_module(part, path)
        # # module = imp.load_module(curname, mp_file, mp_filename, mp_desc)
        import pkgutil
        mp_file = None
        for loadr,name,ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(path=path,prefix='.'.join(modpath[:-1])+'.'):
            if name.split('.')[-1] == part:
                if not hasattr(loadr,'path') and hasattr(loadr,'archive'):
                    # with zips `name` was like '.somemodule'
                    # it gives `RuntimeWarning: Parent module '' not found while handling absolute import`
                    # I expect the name I need to be 'somemodule'
                    # TODO: I don't know why python does this or what the correct usage is.
                    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267984/
                    if name and name[0] == '.':
                        name = name[1:]
                    ldr= loadr.find_module(name,loadr.archive)
                    module = ldr.load_module(name)
                    break
                imploader= loadr.find_module(name,loadr.path)
                mp_file,mp_filename,mp_desc= imploader.file,imploader.filename,imploader.etc
                module = imploader.load_module(imploader.fullname)
                break
        if module is None:
            raise ImportError
```