# How to check if a Python module exists without importing it

Tags: python, python-import

How can I know if a Python module exists, without importing it?

Importing something that might not exist (not what I want) results in:

```
try:
    import eggs
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Comment: I'm curious, what are the downsides to using import?

Comment: If your module has side effects, calling import might have unwanted consequences.  So, if you wanted to check which version of a file to run first, you can do check with the below answer, and do the import later.  I'm not suggesting it is a good idea to write modules with side effects - but we are all adults and can make our own decisions around how dangerously we want to code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if python module exists and can be imported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847934/how-to-check-if-python-module-exists-and-can-be-imported)

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I just closed *that* question you linked as a duplicate of *this* one. Because this question is clearer and also the solution proposed here is better than all other listed there. I'd rather point whoever wants an answer to this better solution than pointing people away from it.

Comment: @Bakuriu - I proposed this one was a duplicate simply based on age. That one predated this one by a year. It doesn't seem logical that the older one could duplicate a newer one. But I do agree this question looks cleaner and has better answers - for that reason, I wrote up a better answer for the question that is now closed after marking this one a duplicate.

Comment: @Bakuriu - Are you able to mark my flag as accepted? Since you've already taken action based on it, there's nothing more to be done with it, so it's pointless for it to continue being marked as active.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare If I ever come accross that question during review I'll take appropriate action. I've tried to filter the close flags by the tags of this question but it didn't show up, and I don't know of any way to review flags relative to a specific question, so, until then, I can't do much about it.

Comment: @Chuck Additionally the module may exist, but may itself contain import errors. Catching ImportErrors as in the code above could lead to indicating the module does not exist, when if fact it does but has errors.

Comment: There are also packages that take quite a long time to import, for various reasons.

Answer (score 313, accepted):

**TL;DR) Use [`importlib.util.find_spec(module_name)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec) (Python 3.4+)**.

### Python2: `imp.find_module`

To check if *import* can find something in Python 2, using `imp`:

```
import imp
try:
    imp.find_module('eggs')
    found = True
except ImportError:
    found = False
```

To find dotted imports, you need to do more:

```
import imp
try:
    spam_info = imp.find_module('spam')
    spam = imp.load_module('spam', *spam_info)
    imp.find_module('eggs', spam.__path__) # __path__ is already a list
    found = True
except ImportError:
    found = False
```

You can also use `pkgutil.find_loader` (more or less the same as the Python 3 part:

```
import pkgutil
eggs_loader = pkgutil.find_loader('eggs')
found = eggs_loader is not None
```

### Python 3

#### Python 3 ≤ 3.3: `importlib.find_loader`

You should use `importlib`. I went about doing this like:

```
import importlib
spam_loader = importlib.find_loader('spam')
found = spam_loader is not None
```

My expectation being, if you can find a loader for it, then it exists.  You can also be a bit more smart about it, like filtering out what loaders you will accept.  For example:

```
import importlib
spam_loader = importlib.find_loader('spam')
# only accept it as valid if there is a source file for the module - no bytecode only.
found = issubclass(type(spam_loader), importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader)
```

#### Python 3 ≥ 3.4: `importlib.util.find_spec`

In Python 3.4 `importlib.find_loader` [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.find_loader) was deprecated in favour of `importlib.util.find_spec`.  The recommended method is the `importlib.util.find_spec`. There are others like `importlib.machinery.FileFinder`, which is useful if you're after a specific file to load.  Figuring out how to use them is beyond the scope of this.

```
import importlib.util
spam_spec = importlib.util.find_spec("spam")
found = spam_spec is not None
```

This also works with relative imports, but you must supply the starting package, so you could also do:

```
import importlib.util
spam_spec = importlib.util.find_spec("..spam", package="eggs.bar")
found = spam_spec is not None
spam_spec.name == "eggs.spam"
```

While I'm sure there exists a reason for doing this - I'm not sure what it would be.

#### Warning

When trying to find a submodule, it will import the parent module (for *ALL* of the above methods)!

```
food/
  |- __init__.py
  |- eggs.py

## __init__.py
print("module food loaded")

## eggs.py
print("module eggs")

were you then to run
>>> import importlib
>>> spam_spec = importlib.util.find_spec("food.eggs")
module food loaded
ModuleSpec(name='food.eggs', loader=<_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10221df28>, origin='/home/user/food/eggs.py')
```

*Comments are welcome on getting around this*

### Acknowledgements

- @rvighne for importlib
- @lucas-guido for Python 3.3+ deprecating `find_loader`
- @enpenax for pkgutils.find_loader behaviour in Python 2.7

Comment: Just a note: there is also `pkgutil.iter_modules()` (via [Alternatives to imp.find_module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741362/alternatives-to-imp-find-module/14820895#14820895))

Comment: This only works for top-level modules, not for `eggs.ham.spam`.

Comment: @hemflit if you want to find `spam` in `eggs.ham` you would use `imp.find_module('spam', ['eggs', 'ham'])`

Comment: +1, but `imp` is [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html) in favor of [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) in Python 3.

Comment: What if the imported module contains an actual "ImportError". That's what was happening to me. Then the module exists but will not be "found".

Comment: After a year I came across the same problem I mentioned just above and was digging for a solution for Python 2: `pkgutil.find_loader("my.package.module")` returns a loader if the package/module exists and `None` if not. Please update your answer for Python 2, as masking the ImportError drove me crazy yesterday xP

Comment: Actually, find_loader was only introduced, but deprecated(!) in 3.3. So that doesn't work for < 3.3.
So `pkgutil.find_loader("my.package.module")` should be the alternative for those versions as well.

Comment: The method with `imp` is not working for me using Python 2.7. `import mpl_toolkits' works fine, but the method you provided returns `False`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec

Comment: If you get an error that `importlib` doesn't have a `util` attribute, you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39661116/210780) for a fix.

Comment: @yarbelk Just a little update: the [ModuleNotFoundError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ModuleNotFoundError) was introduced in python 3.6. A `try` statement with an `except ModuleNotFoundError` can be used for this purpose (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48006925/7170434))

Comment: When I try the code for Python3 ≥ 3.4, I get the error message `AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'`. When adding the row `from importlib import util` after `import importlib`, the error disappears.

Comment: `importlib` appears to be available as early as 2.7. I see no reason to use `imp` if you're not running 2.6 or lower.

Comment: @jpmc26 Importlib in 2.7 has no find_loader. You can only Import the module (Import_module()). Of cause you can use the Import_module function inside try except.

Answer (score 48):

## Python 3 >= 3.6: ModuleNotFoundError

The [`ModuleNotFoundError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ModuleNotFoundError) has been introduced in **Python 3.6** and can be used for this purpose:

```
try:
    import eggs
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    # Error handling
    pass
```

The error is raised when a **module or one of its parents** cannot be found. So

```
try:
    import eggs.sub
except ModuleNotFoundError as err:
    # Error handling
    print(err)
```

would print a message that looks like `No module named 'eggs'` if the `eggs` module cannot be found; but it would print something like `No module named 'eggs.sub'` if only the `sub` module couldn't be found, but the `eggs` package could be found.

See the [documentation of the import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) for more information on the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: This doe not answer the question because it imports the package if it exists

Comment: If another module raises this exception during import, you would not (easily) be able to tell the difference - does your module not exist, or does some of its dependences not exist.

Answer (score 12):

After using [yarbelk's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050281/how-to-check-if-a-python-module-exists-without-importing-it/14050282#14050282), I've made this so I don't have to import `ìmp`.

```
try:
    __import__('imp').find_module('eggs')
    # Make things with a supposed existing module
except ImportError:
    pass
```

It is useful in [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29)'s *settings.py* file, for example.

Comment: I downvoted, because this masks import errors in the module, which makes it really hard to spot the error.

Comment: Downvote is a bad idea, a good pratice is "always log catched errors". This is an example after you write how you want it.

Comment: How would you log an error if the imported module fails on line 1 with an ImportError and your try catch makes it fail silently?

Comment: I've just run into the masking-import-errors issue in real life, and it was bad (causing tests which should have been failing to pass!).

Comment: I ran into that where someone was using that error to trigger a monkeypatch on a different module... that was *madness* to find

Answer (score 12):

### Python 2, without relying on ImportError

Until the current answer is updated, here is the way for **Python 2**

```
import pkgutil
import importlib

if pkgutil.find_loader(mod) is not None:
    return importlib.import_module(mod)
return None
```

#### Why another answer?

A lot of answers make use of catching an `ImportError`. The problem with that is, that we cannot know what throws the `ImportError`.

If you import your *existent* module and there happens to be an `ImportError` in your module (e.g., typo on line 1), the result will be that your module does not exist.

It will take you quite the amount of backtracking to figure out that your module exists and the `ImportError` is caught and makes things fail silently.

Comment: It might have been unclear, but all but the first code blocks do not rely on `ImportError`- please edit if it was unclear to you.

Comment: I see you using the ImportError catch in the first two Python 2 examples. Why are they there, then?

Comment: This throws ImportError if mod == 'not_existing_package.mymodule'. See my full [solution below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35037157/1763149)

Comment: Of course it throws an import error. It is supposed to throw an import error if a module does not exist. That way you can catch it if  you need to. The problem with the other solutions is that they mask other errors.

Comment: Try/except doesn't mean you mustn't not log or ensure things. You can fully catch any underlying traceback and do anything you want with.

Comment: Re *"the current answer"*: Do you mean the *accepted* answer?

Answer (score 7):

[go_as's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050281/how-to-check-if-a-python-module-exists-without-importing-it/29558243#29558243) as a one-liner:

```
 python -c "help('modules');" | grep module
```

Answer (score 5):

Use one of the [functions from pkgutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules), for example:

```
from pkgutil import iter_modules

def module_exists(module_name):
    return module_name in (name for loader, name, ispkg in iter_modules())
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to check if a module is loaded from the **command line**:

**Linux/UNIX script file method**: make a file `module_help.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

help('modules')
```

Then make sure it's executable: `chmod u+x module_help.py`

And call it with a `pipe` to `grep`:

```
./module_help.py | grep module_name
```

> Invoke the built-in [help system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help). (This function is **intended for interactive use**.) If no argument is given, the interactive help system starts on the interpreter console. If the argument is a **string**, then the string is looked up as the name of a **module**, function, class, method, keyword, or documentation topic, and a help page is printed on the console. If the argument is any other kind of object, a help page on the object is generated.

**Interactive method**: in the console, load `python`

```
>>> help('module_name')
```

If found, quit reading by typing `q`.
To exit the Python interpreter interactive session, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

**Windows script file method**, also Linux/UNIX compatible, *and better overall*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

help(sys.argv[1])
```

Calling it from the command like:

```
python module_help.py site
```

Would output:

> Help on module site:
>
> `NAME`
> site - Append module search paths for third-party packages to sys.path.
>
> `FILE`
> /usr/lib/python2.7/site.py
>
> `MODULE DOCS`
> http://docs.python.org/library/site
>
> `DESCRIPTION`
> ...
> :

And you'd have to press `q` to exit interactive mode.

Using it for an unknown module, e.g.,

```
python module_help.py lkajshdflkahsodf
```

Would output:

> no Python documentation found for 'lkajshdflkahsodf'

and exit.

Comment: Nice idea. Like it. Downside: At least on my Win10 the help('modules') command takes what feels like 10 seconds collecting all available modules. If that is no issue, cool command.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote this helper function:

```
def is_module_available(module_name):
    if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
        # python 2
        import importlib
        torch_loader = importlib.find_loader(module_name)
    elif sys.version_info <= (3, 3):
        # python 3.0 to 3.3
        import pkgutil
        torch_loader = pkgutil.find_loader(module_name)
    elif sys.version_info >= (3, 4):
        # python 3.4 and above
        import importlib
        torch_loader = importlib.util.find_spec(module_name)

    return torch_loader is not None
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? How does it compare to the previous answers? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58437485/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

You could just write a little script that would try to import all the modules and tell you which ones are failing and which ones are working:

```
import pip


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for package in pip.get_installed_distributions():
        pack_string = str(package).split(" ")[0]
        try:
            if __import__(pack_string.lower()):
                print(pack_string + " loaded successfully")
        except Exception as e:
            print(pack_string + " failed with error code: {}".format(e))
```

Output:

```
zope.interface loaded successfully
zope.deprecation loaded successfully
yarg loaded successfully
xlrd loaded successfully
WMI loaded successfully
Werkzeug loaded successfully
WebOb loaded successfully
virtualenv loaded successfully
...
```

A word of warning: this will try to import *everything*, so you'll see things like `PyYAML failed with error code: No module named pyyaml`, because the actual import name is just *yaml*. So as long as you know your imports, this should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to reliably check if "dotted module" is importable without importing its parent package. Saying this, there are many solutions to problem "how to check if a Python module exists".

The below solution addresses the problem that an imported module can raise an ImportError even if it exists. We want to distinguish that situation from such in which the module does not exist.

**Python 2**:

```python
import importlib
import pkgutil
import sys

def find_module(full_module_name):
    """
    Returns module object if module `full_module_name` can be imported.

    Returns None if module does not exist.

    Exception is raised if (existing) module raises exception during its import.
    """
    module = sys.modules.get(full_module_name)
    if module is None:
        module_path_tail = full_module_name.split('.')
        module_path_head = []
        loader = True
        while module_path_tail and loader:
            module_path_head.append(module_path_tail.pop(0))
            module_name = ".".join(module_path_head)
            loader = bool(pkgutil.find_loader(module_name))
            if not loader:
                # Double check if module realy does not exist
                # (case: full_module_name == 'paste.deploy')
                try:
                    importlib.import_module(module_name)
                except ImportError:
                    pass
                else:
                    loader = True
        if loader:
            module = importlib.import_module(full_module_name)
    return module
```

**Python 3**:

```python
import importlib

def find_module(full_module_name):
    """
    Returns module object if module `full_module_name` can be imported.

    Returns None if module does not exist.

    Exception is raised if (existing) module raises exception during its import.
    """
    try:
        return importlib.import_module(full_module_name)
    except ImportError as exc:
        if not (full_module_name + '.').startswith(exc.name + '.'):
            raise
```

Comment: it basically does exactly what OP said not to do

Answer (score 1):

In *django.utils.module_loading.module_has_submodule*:

```
import sys
import os
import imp

def module_has_submodule(package, module_name):
    """
    check module in package
    django.utils.module_loading.module_has_submodule
    """
    name = ".".join([package.__name__, module_name])
    try:
        # None indicates a cached miss; see mark_miss() in Python/import.c.
        return sys.modules[name] is not None
    except KeyError:
        pass
    try:
        package_path = package.__path__   # No __path__, then not a package.
    except AttributeError:
        # Since the remainder of this function assumes that we're dealing with
        # a package (module with a __path__), so if it's not, then bail here.
        return False
    for finder in sys.meta_path:
        if finder.find_module(name, package_path):
            return True
    for entry in package_path:
        try:
            # Try the cached finder.
            finder = sys.path_importer_cache[entry]
            if finder is None:
                # Implicit import machinery should be used.
                try:
                    file_, _, _ = imp.find_module(module_name, [entry])
                    if file_:
                        file_.close()
                    return True
                except ImportError:
                    continue
            # Else see if the finder knows of a loader.
            elif finder.find_module(name):
                return True
            else:
                continue
        except KeyError:
            # No cached finder, so try and make one.
            for hook in sys.path_hooks:
                try:
                    finder = hook(entry)
                    # XXX Could cache in sys.path_importer_cache
                    if finder.find_module(name):
                        return True
                    else:
                        # Once a finder is found, stop the search.
                        break
                except ImportError:
                    # Continue the search for a finder.
                    continue
            else:
                # No finder found.
                # Try the implicit import machinery if searching a directory.
                if os.path.isdir(entry):
                    try:
                        file_, _, _ = imp.find_module(module_name, [entry])
                        if file_:
                            file_.close()
                        return True
                    except ImportError:
                        pass
                # XXX Could insert None or NullImporter
    else:
        # Exhausted the search, so the module cannot be found.
        return False
```

Comment: This fulfills my standard question when programming python: WWDD
(What would Django Do?) and I should have look there

Comment: What is the gist of it? E.g., how does it compare to the previous answers (given its increased complexity)? Or should it just be used as a black box without understanding it? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36115385/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `importlib.util` directly

```
import importlib.util    

def module_exists_without_import(module_name):    
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(module_name)
    return spec is not None
```

Comment: This has the problem of actually importing it.  Side effects and all

Answer (score 1):

In case you know the location of file and want to check that the respective Python code file has that module or not, you can simply check via the [astor](https://pypi.org/project/astor/) package in Python. Here is a quick example:

```py
"""
Check if a module function exists or not without importing a Python package file
"""
import ast
import astor

tree = astor.parse_file('handler.py')
method_to_check = 'handle'
for item in tree.body:
    if isinstance(item, ast.FunctionDef):
        if item.name == method_to_check:
            print('method exists')
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler *if* statement from Ask Ubuntu, *[How do I check whether a module is installed in Python?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588390/how-do-i-check-whether-a-module-is-installed-in-python-and-install-it-if-needed)*:

```
import sys
print('eggs' in sys.modules)
```

Comment: This only tests whether it's installed, not whether it's installable.

Comment: Actually, it tests whether it is already **imported**, exact opposite of the question asked.

Comment: The question is "how to check if a python module exists without importing it". Doesn't ask if the module is installable ?