# Distinguish between ImportError because of not found module or faulty import in module itself in python?

Tags: python, import, module, importerror

I have a few modules in python, which are imported dynamicly and all have the same structur (plugin.py, models.py, tests.py, ...). In the managing code i want to import those submodules, but for example models.py or tests.py is not mandatory. (So i could have `plugin_a.plugin` and `plugin_a.tests` but only `plugin_b.plugin`).

I can check if the submodule exists by

```
try:
    __import__(module_name + ".tests")
except ImportError:
    pass
```

That will fail, if `module_name+".tests"` is not found, but it will also fail if the `tests`-module itself will try to import something, which is not found, for example because of a typo.
Is there any way to check if the module exists, without importing it or make sure, the `ImportError` is only raised by one specific import-action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know what the import error message will look like if the module doesn't exist so just check for that:

```
try:
    module = module_name + '.tests'
    __import__(module)
except ImportError, e:
    if e.args and e.args[0] == 'No module named ' + module:
        print(module, 'does not exist')
    else:
        print(module, 'failed to import')
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'm a little bit concerned about depending on the exact wording of the error-message, but maybee i just check if the module is in the error-string:)

Comment: @Daishy - yeah, could result in non-obvious failure later. Just account for submodules. module.tests.froob contains module.tests but shouldn't match your test.

Answer (score 3):

You can see from the *length of the traceback* how many levels deep the import failed. A missing `.test` module has a traceback with just one frame, a direct dependency failing has two frames, etc.

Python 2 version, using [`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) to access the traceback:

```
import sys


try:
    __import__(module_name + ".tests")
except ImportError:
    if sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_next is not None:
        print "Dependency import failed"
    else:
        print "No module {}.tests".format(module_name)
```

Python 3 version, where [exceptions have a `__traceback__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement):

```
try:
    __import__(module_name + ".tests")
except ImportError as exc:
    if exc.__traceback__.tb_next is not None:
        print("Dependency import failed")
    else:
        print("No module {}.tests".format(module_name))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import sys
>>> def direct_import_failure(name):
...     try:
...         __import__(name)
...     except ImportError:
...         return sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_next is None
... 
>>> with open('foo.py', 'w') as foo:
...     foo.write("""\
... import bar
... """)
... 
>>> direct_import_failure('bar')
True
>>> direct_import_failure('foo')
False
```

Comment: Cute. This seems like the most flexible and reliable answer so far.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from: [How to check if a python module exists without importing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050281/how-to-check-if-a-python-module-exists-without-importing-it)

The [`imp.find_module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) function will either return a 3-element tuple (file, pathname, description) or raise an ImportError.

It will not raise an error if there is a problem with the module, only if it doesn't exist.

The python docs suggest that you should first find and import the package and then use its **path** in second `find_module`, doing this recursively if necessary.

This seems a little messy to me.

The function below will check for the existence of a given module, at any level of relative import (`module.py`, `package.module.py`, `package.subpackage.module.py` etc.).

`imp.find_module` returns an open file, which you could use in `imp.load_module`, but this, too seems a little clunky, so I close the file so that it can be imported outside of the function.

Note that this isn't perfect. if you are looking for `package.subpackage.module` but actually `package.subpackage` is a valid module it will also return true.

```
import imp
import importlib

def module_exists(modulename):
    modlist = modulename.split('.')
    pathlist = None
    for mod in modlist:
        print mod
        try:
            openfile, pathname, desc = imp.find_module(mod,pathlist)
            pathlist = [pathname]
        except ImportError:
            print "Module '{}' does not exist".format(mod)
            return(False)
        else:
            print 'found {}'.format(openfile)
            if openfile:
                openfile.close()
                return(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mymodule = 'parrot.type.norwegian_blue'
    if module_exists(mymodule):
        importlib.import_module(mymodule)
```

Note also that I'm using `importlib.import_module` instead of `__import__`.

Finally, note that [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) is Python 2.7 and upwards

Comment: Updated code to better support any level of relative imports.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to check if the module exists, without importing it
>   or make sure, the ImportError is only raised by one specific
>   import-action?

There could be multiple reasons why `ImportError` fails because importing will evaluate the module; if there is a syntax error the module will fail to load.

To check if a module exists without loading it, use [`pkgutil.find_loader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.find_loader), like this:

```
>>> pkgutil.find_loader('requests')
<pkgutil.ImpLoader instance at 0x9a9ce8c>
>>> pkgutil.find_loader('foo')
```

It will return either a `ImpLoader` instance, or `None` if the package is not importable. You can get further details from the `ImpLoader` instance, like the path of the module:

```
>>> pkgutil.find_loader('django').filename
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django'
```

Comment: Nice, although this still isn't a general solution because it doesn't support relative imports. (`ImportError: Relative module names not supported`)