# create a class only if a package is available on the system

Tags: python

I have classes in a Python project that depend on an external packages. I would like these classes to be created only if their dependencies are available.

For example, how can I have a class `YamlParser` which only exists if `yaml` can be imported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this within a `try` - `except` block.

However, this can highly complicate things if you want to access the class in other places, as the error handling will become more and more complex.

```
try:
    import yaml
    Class YamlParser():
        pass
except ImportError:
    pass
    #error handling here
```

You can also see [How to check if a python module exists without importing it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14050281/1860929) for ways to do this without the import statement.

Comment: Agreed, it's better to import every package in the start of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Use try and except to handle this cases:

```
try:
    import yaml
    ## your code goes here
except ImportError:
    ## here you handle the expcetion
```

Answer (score 0):

The modular and extensible solution is to put `YamlParser` in its own source file, and simply put the `import yaml` statement at the beginning. Any code which tries to `import` this code will fail if the required module `yaml` is missing.