# How to tell the difference between an import error because the file doesn't exist, compared to that it doesn't parse

Tags: python, import, exception

I have a case where a module may optionally exist.   If it doesn't exist, it's OK.

I wrote this:

```
try:
    import debug_trace
    print "[FEATURE_TEST] ... loaded custom debug traces, from %s" % debug_trace.__file__
except ImportError:
    # The file "debug_trace.py" probably doesn't exist
    pass
```

then I realised that this is not achieving what I want, because it masks errors in the case where the file exists but it contains errors.

How can I safely import a module, if it exists... but, report errors if it contains them?

Comment: But I've just tried your code and it's working. What's the error you're getting?

Comment: What parse error you are referring to?..like syntax error or what?..I'm just trying to understand your point here

Comment: I think the distinction is pretty irrelevant, you should not have any files with flat out syntax errors in them in the first place; that's something that needs to be caught by your IDE/text editor/development workflow. It's not something to care about in code.

Comment: The case here is that the users of this system may supply a debug_trace module on the python path.   If they don't supply it, it's not a problem.  If they do supply it, but it has python syntax or other errors, then it is a problem.  I am trying to ask how to differentiate between these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this

[[How to check if a python module exists without importing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050281/how-to-check-if-a-python-module-exists-without-importing-it][1])

So in your particular case I would combine Thomas' answer and your code

```
import imp
try:
    imp.find_module('debug_trace')
    found = True
except ImportError:
    print "Module debug_trace not found"
    found = False
    pass

if found:
    try:
        import debug_trace
        print "[FEATURE_TEST] ... loaded custom debug traces, from %s" % debug_trace.__file__
    except ImportError:
        # The file "debug_trace.py" exists but importation fails
        pass
```

Comment: This sounds great.  The only problem is it doesn't work.   To confirm this, I put a print statement in the module to be imported, then did import module.  It printed.  Then I replaced the import with the find_module, and it threw ImportError, saying the module didn't exist!    The only thing I can think of is that import looks in the current working directory, whearas find_module doesn't?