# exception if module does not exist

Tags: python, python-module

Is it possible to do try exception (or something else) if a module exists or not?
I have a code as(all of them are defined, just not included here):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def scf:
    A = np.array(plist, dtype="float")
    np.savetxt("foo.dat", A,
                delimiter=' ', fmt="%1.4e")

    plt.plot(A[:, 0], A[:, 4], label="foo", linewidth="4.")
    plt.show()
```

It writes `foo.dat` and also plots it. What I am trying to achieve is:

```
def scf:
    A = np.array(plist, dtype="float")
    # if matplotlib does not exists, write to file
    np.savetxt("foo.dat", A,
                delimiter=' ', fmt="%1.4e")
    #else if matplotlib exists, show plot, dont write to file
    plt.plot(A[:, 0], A[:, 4], label="foo", linewidth="4.")
    plt.show()
```

Can I do that?

Comment: Look here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050281/how-to-check-if-a-python-module-exists-without-importing-it

Answer (score 0):

Importing a module that does not exist will raise `ImportError`, which you can catch like any other exception with a try/except block.