# Error when using importlib.util to check for library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib

I'm trying to use the importlib library to verify whether the nmap library is installed on the computer executing the script in Python 3.5.2

I'm trying to use `importlib.util.find_spec("nmap")` but receive the following error.

```
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.util.find_spec("nmap")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'
```

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

**EDIT**

I was able to get the function to work using the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/pythonw

import importlib
from importlib import util

#check to see if nmap module is installed
find_nmap = util.find_spec("nmap")
if find_nmap is None:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: Might be stating the obvious, but did you do `import importlib` before trying to use `importlib`?

Comment: @ldjaw yes my apologies for not stating that in the question. Edited question for clarity.

Comment: @idjaw just tried and no love :( Same error message.

Comment: try `from importlib import util`

Comment: I tried this it says util doesnt exist

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
from importlib import util
util.find_spec("nmap")
```

I intend to investigate, but honestly I don't know why one works and the other doesn't. Also, observe the following interactive session:

```
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.util
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'
>>> from importlib import util
>>> util
<module 'importlib.util' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/util.py'>
>>> importlib.util
<module 'importlib.util' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/util.py'>
```

So...yeah. I am sure this makes perfect sense to someone, but not to me. I will update once I figure it out.

## Update:

Comparing this to something like:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime
<module 'datetime' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/datetime.py'>
>>> datetime.datetime
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

I think the difference is that in this case the first `datetime` is a module and the second is a class, while in the `importlib.util` case both are modules. So perhaps `module.module` is not OK unless the code from both modules has been loaded, while `module.class` is OK, because the class code is loaded when the module is imported.

## Update #2

Nope, it seems like in many cases `module.module` is fine. For example:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib
<module 'urllib' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/__init__.py'>
>>> urllib.error
<module 'urllib.error' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/error.py'>
```

So perhaps it is something specific to `importlib`.

## Update #3

As **@kfb** pointed out in the comments, it does seem to be related to `importlib` specifically. See the following comment from the [`__init__.py` for `importlib`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/importlib/__init__.py):

```
# Until bootstrapping is complete, DO NOT import any modules that attempt
# to import importlib._bootstrap (directly or indirectly). Since this
# partially initialised package would be present in sys.modules, those
# modules would get an uninitialised copy of the source version, instead
# of a fully initialised version (either the frozen one or the one
# initialised below if the frozen one is not available).
```

`importlib/util.py` *does* import `importlib._bootstrap` so I would assume that this is realted. If my understanding is correct, when you do `import importlib` the submodules will be initialized, but are not initialized for the `importlib` module object that you have imported. At this point, if you do `dir(importlib)` you will not see `util`. Interestingly, *after* you have tried to access `importlib.util` and gotten an `AttributeError`, `util` (along with the other submodules) gets loaded/initialized, and now you *can* access `importlib.util`!

```
>>> import importlib
>>> dir(importlib)
['_RELOADING', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__import__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '_bootstrap', '_bootstrap_external', '_imp', '_r_long', '_w_long', 'find_loader', 'import_module', 'invalidate_caches', 'reload', 'sys', 'types', 'warnings']
>>> importlib.util
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'
>>> importlib.util
<module 'importlib.util' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/util.py'>
>>> dir(importlib)
['_RELOADING', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__import__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '_bootstrap', '_bootstrap_external', '_imp', '_r_long', '_w_long', 'abc', 'find_loader', 'import_module', 'invalidate_caches', 'machinery', 'reload', 'sys', 'types', 'util', 'warnings']
```

Comment: Beautiful - looks like this works! This returns nothing which I understand means it's working as it should. Thank you!

Comment: @DKNUCKLES, great! Not sure why it doesn't work the other way...See the weird interactive session in my updated answer.

Comment: thank you for this. I wish I could upvote your answer more than once for the work you put into helping. I've been able to cobble something together that has worked for me which I'll post in my question.

Comment: It would seem that [`importlib` does not include `util` directly](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/importlib/__init__.py).

Comment: @DKNUCKLES no problem! I am happy when interesting problems like yours come up. It is a great opportunity to learn for both the asker and the answerer!

Comment: @kfb what do you mean by "does not include directly"?

Comment: @kfb Ah, OK. I think I see what you mean: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/importlib/__init__.py#l6

Comment: @DKNUCKLES OK, this is my last update, I promise ;) Check out Update 3 for some interesting new discoveries.

Comment: @elethan thanks again!  Your assistance is definitely appreciated :)

Comment: @elethan did you try import importlib.util ?