# Write strings/text and pandas dataframe to excel

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'd like to save some text and a dataframe to an excel file like that:
[image]

Thus, I've got the following variables:

```
text1 = "some text here"
text2 = "other text here"
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4,5], "b": [6,7,8,9,10], "c": [11,12,13,14,15]})
```

As I've figured out there is the possibility to use the xlsxwriter to do this which means that I basically have to iterate over the whole dataframe to write each entry to a different cell in the excel workbook. This is quite cumbersome.

So, I thought there must an easier way to do this; something like this:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
writer.write(text1, startrow=0, startcol=0)
writer.write(text1, startrow=1, startcol=0)
df.to_excel(writer, startrow=4, startcol=0)
```

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need [`write` or `write_string`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html):

```
text1 = "some text here"
text2 = "other text here"
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,4,5], "b": [6,7,8,9,10], "c": [11,12,13,14,15]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
df.to_excel(writer, startrow=4, startcol=0)

worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.write(0, 0, text1)
worksheet.write(1, 0, text2)
#another solution
#worksheet.write_string(0, 0, text1)
#worksheet.write_string(1, 0, text2)

writer.save()
```

**Note:**
`write` and `write_string` are actually `xlsxwriter` package functions. To use them, the package must be installed and `pd.ExcelWriter` must be initialized with the `xlsxwriter` engine (in pandas 1.0.5 it defaults to the [io.excel.<extension>.writer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) engine)

Comment: how does Sheet1 get added?

Comment: @MikePalmice - It is default value, but if need custom use `df.to_excel(writer, startrow=4, startcol=0, sheet_name ='aaa')

worksheet = writer.sheets['aaa']`

Comment: right but `worksheet = writer.sheets['aaa']` doesnt create a new sheet if it doesnt exist. also i'm getting 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'write' or 'write_string'

Comment: @MikePalmice - Yes, `worksheet = writer.sheets['aaa']` only select sheetname called `aaa`. I think if get this error, is necessary upgrade pandas.

Comment: pandas: 0.23.4, python: 3.7.0

Comment: i tried with your sample code and got the same error. can OP or anyone else try running, and if it works, share their system info plz?

Comment: Im getting 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'write' same error for write-string too

Comment: To use the `write_string` or `write` methods, `pd.ExcelWriter` must me initialized with `engine='xlsxwriter'` and the `xlsxwriter` package needs to be installed. Credit [@SonOfLight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54072373/11715606)

Answer (score 3):

Above solution is correct... However

The write function is part of the xlsxwriter library.
When declaring the writer you need to indicate what engine you want pandas to use.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
```

xlsxwriters functions are then usable through pandas. All other code in the above solution stays the same.

Ofcourse you require the library to be installed. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050281/how-to-check-if-a-python-module-exists-without-importing-it) is a programmatic check.

*Would comment but rep to low*

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the openpyxl package:

```
import pandas as pd
df = <pandas dataframe>
with pd.ExcelWriter(filename) as writer:
    text = "Text message"
    text_sheet = writer.book.create_sheet(title='text_sheet')
    text_sheet.cell(column=1, row=1, value=text)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'df_sheet', index = False)
```

This won't put it on the same sheet though.