# Cannot write to an excel AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I am trying to write text to an excel I am following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537598/write-strings-text-and-pandas-dataframe-to-excel).  This was working earlier but now it is not.  I get:

Error:

```
line 122, in <module>
    worksheet.write(0, 11, 'HI')
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'write'
```

df1

```
A  E
c  d
c  D
```

Code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("C:\\33.xlsx")
df1.to_excel(writer, startrow=0, startcol=0, index = False)

worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.write(0, 11, 'YO')
worksheet.write(1, 11, 'HI')
```

I have tried also:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy
import os.path
rb = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\13.xlsx',formatting_info=True)
r_sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0) 
wb = copy(rb) 
sheet = wb.get_sheet(0) 
sheet.write(5,2,"string")
wb.save('C:\\13.xlsx')
```

I get:

```
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\13.xlsx"'
```

How do I fix `AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'write'`

Answer (score 18):

The reason it gives: `AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'write'`

Is because I realised I have not installed xlsxwriter on this pc.

```
pip install xlsxwriter
```

Now it works.

Comment: If you explicitly want to use XlsxWriter then you should probably add `engine='xlsxwriter'` to `pd.ExcelWriter()` otherwise Pandas could substitute OpenPyXL if that is available and XlsxWriter is not. Hence the missing method error. If you aren't using XlsxWriter specific methods then it doesn't matter which engine is used.