# Pandas dataframe with dynamic title

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

Suppose I have the following `dataframe`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})
```

I want to give it a title provided by user e.g.:
`title = 'The sales'`

How can I add the `title` to the `df` such that when send to `Excel sheet` or `pdf` it appears as:
`

```
{title} in this case *The sales*
 A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b
```

Searching for possible solutions leads to adding `column` `title`, while what I want is adding `dataframe` title.

Comment: Don't think you can do that (because that's not how tables work) but you can just: `f = open(fp); f.write(title); f.write(df.to_string)`

Comment: @StefanFalk, `f.write(title)` demands that `title` be a `string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using xlsxwriter as the Pandas Excel engine. Something similar would also be possible using openpyxl:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('abcdef'),
                   'B': [4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4],
                   'C': [7, 8, 9, 4, 2, 3],
                   'D': [1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 0],
                   'E': [5, 3, 6, 9, 2, 4],
                   'F': list('aaabbb')})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Shift the dataframe down one row in the Excel file.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Write the title to the worksheet.
title = 'The sales'
worksheet.write(0, 0, title)

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537598/write-strings-text-and-pandas-dataframe-to-excel/69343572#69343572

Answer (score 0):

You can use xlwings, it is one of the best libraries to get your data into excel using python

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})


title = 'The sales'

wb = xw.Book("sales.xlsx")

sheet = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

sheet.range('A1').value = title

sheet.range('A2').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = df

wb.save('sales.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

#If you dont need Index keep above
#If you need Index put index=True

Comment: `xlwings` seem not meant for `Ubuntu`

Comment: Ahh you should mention the details in the question that you are using ubuntu