# Import python package in the module

Tags: python, import, module, package

I am beginner in Python. I am using set python libraries and I want to take the part of my code in .py module. Where should I write "import" of the set of libraries, in the module, or in main file? If I don't write it in the module, program doesn't work.

```
#mainfile.py
import cv2
import faceResearch
faceResearch.mn()

#faceResearch.py
import cv2
def mn():
    image = cv2.imread("Smiling/3--1873301-Smiling woman looking at camera.jpg")
    cv2.imshow("im", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

so, in which file should I write "import cv2"? in mainfile? in file of the module? or in both?

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried.  It's unclear exactly what your question is asking

Comment: Please add your code as an example

Comment: Thank You, I've done it.

Comment: Why do you want to separate `mainfile.py` and `faceResearch.py`? Both are technically modules, and if all you want to do is execute the code in `faceResearch.py` you should get rid of `mainfile.py` and run `faceResearch.py` directly.

Comment: It is only excample, I will have classes and methods in faceResearch.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep `import cv2` in  your module (**faceResearch.py** ?) not in **main.py**. With that all others scripts importing your module will automatically import `cv2` ; if `cv2` is installed. You can check if `cv2` is installed, and if not display an error message : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14050281/4896841)

Comment: Thank you) I Should I use special file for imports and add in in each module? Because I will have much of libraries, not only cv2.

Comment: To summarize : each time you wrote `cv2` in a file, put `import cv2` in this file.

Comment: @ДанилаМантуров if this solves your issue, pls pass the post as resolved, else ask for precision.