# Why does this python script only fail when run from the command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian, email

I have a small python project that runs on a raspberry pi. It monitors temperatures, checks and sends emails, and controls a PDU. It runs perfectly from the Thonny IDE included in raspbian. However when I run it from the command line, or ideally on startup, it fails in one specific section of code dealing with checking emails.

I installed the email module on the system using pip install. Then I realized this was standard in python so i uninstalled it.

This is the error code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Python Files/Temp_Monitor_Project/temp_controller.py", line 122, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Python Files/Temp_Monitor_Project/temp_controller.py", line 104, in main
    check_email_com(state_and_monitoring)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Python Files/Temp_Monitor_Project/temp_controller.py", line 16, in check_email_com
    command = check_email.check_for_commands()
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Python Files/Temp_Monitor_Project/check_email.py", line 43, in check_for_commands
    command = message.checkMail()
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Python Files/Temp_Monitor_Project/check_email.py", line 20, in checkMail
    email_msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'message_from_bytes'
```

Here is the script it fails in.

```
import imaplib, struct, time, email, Send_Email

#global sender

class Mail():
    def __init__(self):
        self.user= 'email address'
        self.password= 'password'
        self.M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', '993')
        try:
            self.M.login(self.user, self.password)
        except:
            print("mail login failed")

    def checkMail(self):
        self.M.select()
        self.unRead = self.M.search(None, '(SUBJECT "Temp Monitor Command" UnSeen)')
        if len(self.unRead[1][0].split()) > 0:
            status, data = self.M.fetch(self.unRead[1][0], '(RFC822)')
            email_msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
            if email_msg.is_multipart():
                for part in email_msg.walk():       
                    if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                        body = part.get_payload(decode=True) 
                        body = body.decode()

                    elif part.get_content_type() == "text/html":
                        continue
            #print(self.M.fetch(self.unRead[1][0], "(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)])"))
            return body
        else:
            return -1
```

Comment: Did you name one of your own modules `email`? Why are you expecting `email` to have a `message_from_bytes` function?

Comment: When you run from the command line, which version of python are you using? The docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_bytes mention that the message_from_bytes function was introduced in 3.2.

Comment: @DonRowe I am VERY new to python. I did not realize that the command line call determined the python version used i.e. python script.py could also be python3 script.py. 

I have just been running it as python script.py & so it would always run 2.x and exclude message_from_bytes. Thanks.

Comment: @DonRowe: what the - that is a frustrating place for top-level module contents to be documented.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is nearby environment where you try to execute your code. Try to check installed modules in both cases. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14050282/604475) about How to list of used modules during execution. Also you should check which python instance used in both cases. To do this you can execute this

```
import sys 
print(sys.executable)
print(sys.version)
```