# Why is pydroid3 keep telling me "there is no attribute.. in module..?"

Tags: python

I have 2 modules A and B

A

```
def f(x):
     
    return x*2
```

B

```
import A
x=7
print(A.f(x))
```

When I run B I get error `module A has no attribute f` why?

Comment: Are `A.py` and `B.py` in the same folder, and does that folder also contain an empty file called `__init__.py`? If not, can you try adding that file and doing so?

Comment: Related - See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050281/how-to-check-if-a-python-module-exists-without-importing-it), on how to check if a module exists without importing it.

Comment: After `import A`, add `print(A.__file__)`. Is the file you think it is?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. If I write two files A.py and B.py in hte same directory, then run `python3 b.py`, it works. So, we have to guess what's different in your environment. You say modules A and B... do you mean A.py and B.py? Are these in an IDE? Have you saved the files before running?

Comment: Its is better if you can provide tree of the directory for the program.