# least burdensome technique for package submodule to see all classes of importer

Tags: python, module, package, global

### Background Problem

A python program imports some modules, which each creates various classes.  It also imports a package with submodules, which need to be able to see all the classes available at the top-level of the python program.  How can the package submodule see all the classes available to its importer?

Here is my current solution, which works, but it requires the top-level program to create an instance from the sub-module and pass in the `globals()` dictionary via an instance method (see below).  At least it only has to be done once after importing the package's submodules.

What would be a better approach that does **not** require the top-level program to pass in its `globals()`?  I would like for this to happen automatically, transparently to the top-level program, if possible.

### Output with Comments

```
$ python top_t.py 
Hi, I'm an instance of ModM!
# Expected, but not desired.
ModM in SubModS:0's globals = No
Adding globals from higher level to level of SubModS.
# Yeah!
ModM in SubModS:0's globals = Yes
# Persistent
ModM in SubModS:1's globals = Yes
# Sufficient to create a new instance from submodule.
Hi, I'm an instance of ModM!
```

### Code

**top_t.py**

```
from mod_m import ModM
from package_p import SubModS

m0 = ModM()
s0 = SubModS(0)

s0.see_class('ModM')
s0.broaden_view(globals())
s0.see_class('ModM')
s1 = SubModS(1)
s1.see_class('ModM')
m1 = s0.create_inst('ModM')
```

**mod_m.py**

```
class ModM(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Hi, I'm an instance of ModM!"
```

**package_p/__init__.py**

```
__all__ = ['SubModS']
from .submod_s import SubModS
```

**package_p/submod_s.py**

```
class SubModS(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def see_class(self, cls):
        print "{} in {}:{}'s globals = {}".format(cls, self.__class__.__name__, self.i, 'Yes' if cls in globals() else 'No')
    def broaden_view(self, higher_globals):
        print 'Adding globals from higher level to level of {}.'.format(self.__class__.__name__)
        local_globals = globals()
        for nm, ob in higher_globals.iteritems():
            if nm not in local_globals:
                local_globals[nm] = ob
    def create_inst(self, cls):
        return globals()[cls]()
```

Comment: There isn't really such a thing as "the top level" in the way you're describing.  Each module just has an independent namespace.  Trying to do this is just going to make your code obtuse.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Why does SubModS need access to "all the classes" from its importer, instead of just importing what it needs itself?

Comment: I want the package to be extensible.  It needs to know all of the classes matching a specific API that are imported along side of it, so the package can also use them.  (Think of them as "plug-ins".)  But, I don't want to hard-code these plug-ins names as imports inside the package, and I'd like to minimize the burden on the package users, so they don't have to inject the plug-in names into the package.  I want the package to "discover" available plug-ins.  And, I do not want any directory, file-space limitations.

Comment: I think using a directory-based system is probably much simpler.  But if you don't want to do that, you may be better off iterating through `sys.modules` looking for modules that match your target API (however you determine that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about BrenBarn's comments and exploring (googling) Python plugin frameworks, I decided to make a very simple one suitable for my needs, based on the following links:

- http://martyalchin.com/2008/jan/10/simple-plugin-framework/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17401329/538418

A modified version of the above example looks like the following (see below).

The key is using a meta-class to collect a list of all classes based on a central convenience, base class.

### Program Output

```
$ python top_t.py
Hi, I'm instance #0 of SubModS!
Can ModM be seen by SubModS:0?  Yes!
Can UnBasedClass be seen by SubModS:0?  No!
Hi, I'm instance #0 of ModM!
Hi, I'm instance #1 of ModM!
Can SubModS be seen by ModM:1?  Yes!
Hi, I'm instance #1 of SubModS!
```

### Code

**top_t.py**

```
from mod_m import ModM
from package_p import SubModS

s0 = SubModS()
s0.see_class('ModM')
s0.see_class('UnBasedClass')
s0.create_inst('ModM')

m0 = ModM()
m0.see_class('SubModS')
m0.create_inst('SubModS')
```

**mod_m.py**

```
from package_p import PluginBase
class ModM(PluginBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ModM, self).__init__()
```

**package_p/__init__.py**

```
__all__ = ['SubModS', 'PluginBase']
from .meta_base import PluginBase
from .submod_s import SubModS
```

**package_p/submod_s.py**

```
from .meta_base import PluginBase
class SubModS(PluginBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubModS, self).__init__()
```

**package_p/meta_base.py**

```
class PluginMount(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'plugins'):
            cls.plugins = []
        else:
            cls.plugins.append(cls)

class PluginBase(object):
    __metaclass__ = PluginMount
    i = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = self.__class__.i
        print "Hi, I'm instance #{} of {}!".format(self.i, self.__class__.__name__)
        self.__class__.i += 1
    def see_class(self, name):
        print "Can {} be seen by {}:{}?  {}!".format(name, self.__class__.__name__, self.i, 'Yes' if name in (cls.__name__ for cls in self.__class__.plugins) else 'No')
    def create_inst(self, name):
        for cls in self.__class__.plugins:
            if name == cls.__name__:
                return cls()
        return None
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Other approaches and comments are certainly welcome.

Thanks!